What polls are there within EU whether people agree with given support for Israel?
There have been many protests in the world and in America and Europe against Israel's alleged war crimes in Gaza.
What polls are there (within this year) within the EU zone considering whether people agree with the given support for israel? Politically, financially or militarily.

EU zone is not so homogenous and coherent as thought sometimes. What about polls that only cover part of the EU zone? Are you interested in them too?

A quick Google search for "support for israel europe poll" finds plenty of results. You can also restrict to results from 2024 and later if you wish. Here're some of them:

Support for Israel's war on Gaza has dropped in Europe, poll finds
Public Opinion Poll: How 5 European countries see Palestinian issues
68% of Germans oppose military support for Israel: Survey
Why Israel has not yet lost Europe

Broadly speaking, a majority of Europeans (at least in the countries polled) think Israel has gone too far, but (according to the last source) their votes aren't driven by this issue.
